# How do I pass the context from the top level serializer to the contained serializers with Django REST framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

```
class EmployerContactFullSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    email_addresses = EmployerContactEmailSerializer(source='email_address_set', many=True)
```

In this case I'm deserializing and EmployerContact, and it contains N EmployerContactEmailAddresses.  The EmployerContactFullSeriailzer has a self.context that is populated, but the EmployerContactEmailSerializer does not get this context when it is instantiated.

How do I get that context into the lower level serializers?

Comment: can you post your models and your full serializer?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers#including-extra-context) on including extra context.

In your view, try this instead:

```
serializer = EmployerContactEmailSerializer(account, context={'request': request})
```

Comment: @Mark0978 Please check my updated answer. I came across this part of the docs to day and I think it might solve your problem. Could you please post your view as well?